# xcassets and In-House Deployment

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, xcasset

Thank's to everyone who take the time to read this. Sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem with the images on my iOS app.

On my device and on the simulator: there are no problem. But after the in-house deployment, there are no image on the downloaded application. Nothing. I don't understand why...

I only have one loaded image. The image which was not in xcassets.

I verified that the images were well within the target application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your xcassets bundle is in your your copy bundle build phase.

Targets -> "App" -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> check to see if "Images.xcassets" (or other name if you've renamed) is in that list; if not, add it.